# Inserting an image, as well as other data in to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a student trying to create a swap site for uni. I've hit upon an issue. I've searched all the posts and there are some similar, but when I try to change my code to match everything breaks. Please be kind or at least try, I am learning.

I have tried to change the code entirely for the file upload but I'm seriously lost. I have a login and user database that works fine, but for some reason I can't get my item data to save in the 'item' database. I just got the message file not uploaded.

I'm trying to store information about the item being posted and the image as well as entering a timestamp and username from the session.

This is the database setup for the Item:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `itemid` int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `iname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `idescription` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `itype` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `icolour` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `icategory` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `idate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `username` varchar(60) NOT NULL
);
```

And this is the code of the php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['userSession']) || isset($_SESSION['userSession']) && empty($_SESSION['userSession']) ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-postitem'])) {

    $iname = $_POST['iname'];
    $idescription = $_POST['idescription'];
    $itype = $_POST['itype'];
    $icolour = $_POST['icolour'];
    $icategory = $_POST['icategory'];

    $uploadDir = "upload/"; 
    $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
    $username = $_SESSION['userSession'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"upload/".$_FILES['image']['name']) ){
        $query_image = "INSERT INTO item(iname,idescription,itype,icolour,icategory,image,idate,username) VALUES('$iname','$idescription','$itype','$icolour','$icategory','$filePath','curdate()','$username')";


                // insert the image into db
        if(mysql_query($query_image)) {
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES['image']['name'];
             }
        else{
            echo "File name not stored in database";
        }
                }
                else{
                        echo 'File not uploaded';
                    }
         }
$db1->close();
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Post Item</title>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="signin-form">

    <div class="container">


        <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="register-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Post Item</h2><hr />

        <?php
        if (isset($msg)) {
            echo $msg;
        }
        ?>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Name" name="iname" required  />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" name="idescription" required  />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type of Item" name="itype" required  />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Colour" name="icolour" required  />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Category" name="icategory" required  />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Picture" name="image" required  />
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn-postitem">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Post Item
        </button> 

        </div> 

      </form>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you create the "upload" directory? Put this code before `session_start()` line: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Now you should see why your code doesn't work. Consider using mysqli or, better, PDO, because mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. And use prepared statements for avoiding SQL injections.

Comment: Define field `itemid` as `unsigned` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Otherwise it will receive value 0 on insert.

Comment: If you defined `idate` as you did, then you should not include the field (and the `curdate()` value) in the `INSERT` statement. It will be automatically gain the current date-time on insert. Otherwise, if you use `curdate()` in the sql statement, the `idate` field will receive the value `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your **image column must be BLOB type!**

We got fields `id` (int), `image` (blob) and `image_name` (varchar(64)).

So the code should look like this (assume ID is always '1' and let's use this mysql_query):

```
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); //SQL Injection defence!
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `product_images` (`id`, `image`, `image_name`) VALUES ('1', '{$image}', '{$image_name}')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) { // Error handling
echo "Something went wrong! :(";
```

}

MySQL functions - they are deprecated! Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). You should also think about storing files locations on disk. Handling SQL table with big data like images can be problematic.

Also your HTML should look like this:

```
<form action="insert_product.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>File: </label><input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Sidenote:

When dealing with files and storing them as a BLOB, the data must be escaped using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), otherwise it will result in a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now without changing to using blobs. Thought I'd post the code so if anyone else is doing the same it might help. All I have to do now is show the table set out like e-bay and add a few search options.

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['userSession']) || isset($_SESSION['userSession']) && empty($_SESSION['userSession']) ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-postitem'])) {

    $iname = $_POST['iname'];
    $idescription = $_POST['idescription'];
    $itype = $_POST['itype'];
    $icolour = $_POST['icolour'];
    $icategory = $_POST['icategory'];

    $uploadDir = "upload/"; 
    $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
    $username = $_SESSION['userName'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$filePath) ){

             echo "name: "; var_dump($iname);echo '<br>';
               echo "desc: "; var_dump($idescription);echo '<br>';
               echo "type: "; var_dump($itype);echo '<br>';
               echo "colour: "; var_dump($icolour);echo '<br>';
               echo "category: "; var_dump($icategory);echo '<br>';
               echo "filePath: "; var_dump($filePath);echo '<br>';
               echo "username: "; var_dump($username);echo '<br>';



        $query_image = "INSERT INTO item(iname,idescription,itype,icolour,icategory,image,username) VALUES('$iname','$idescription','$itype','$icolour','$icategory','$filePath','$username')";


                // insert the image into db
        if ($db1->query($query_image)) {
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES['image']['name'];
             }
        else{
            echo "File name not stored in database";
        }
                }
                else{
                        echo 'File not uploaded';
                    }
         }
$db1->close();
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Post Item</title>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="signin-form">

    <div class="container">


        <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="register-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Post Item</h2><hr />

        <?php
        if (isset($msg)) {
            echo $msg;
        }
        ?>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Name" name="iname" required  />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" name="idescription" required  />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type of Item" name="itype" required  />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Colour" name="icolour" required  />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Category" name="icategory" required  />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Picture" name="image" required  />
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn-postitem">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Post Item
        </button>
            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;">Home</a>

        </div> 

      </form>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```